# Ordinary Differential Equation for Suspension Bridge

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume the soldiers are marching at a constant speed $v$, and at $t=0$ the column of soldiers are just about to enter the bridge. That means after time $T=L/v$ the soldier at the front of the row will reach the other side of the bridge.

$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+f(x,t)$$ $$0<x<L$$$$0<t<T$$

$$u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$$ $$0<t<T$$

$$u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$$ $$0<x<L$$

Now I know we are using the forcing function $\alpha sin(2\pi t/P)$ for $t≥T$ and I am trying to come up with the forcing function $f(x,t)$ for $0<x<L$, $0<t<T$

Comment: I might be confused, but your conditions say $0<t<T$, that is, solve for $t<T$, that is $t>T$ is not a part of the problem.  But you describe the forcing function for $t>T$ anyway.  Did I misunderstand?  Also, I think this sounds like a homework problem, but it seems strange for homework.  There just is no obvious, unique form of the forcing function.  As a research project, it might be interesting to try a few different functions, but as a homework problem?  Doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the soldiers are marching "in step" so at all points where there are soldiers the force per unit distance is the same, while where there are no soldiers there is no force.  At time $t=0$ the front of the column is at $x=0$,
at $t=T = L/v$ it is at $x=L$, so since they are marching at constant speed 
the front is at $x = tv$ at time $t$.  There is no mention of a back of the column, so presumably that doesn't reach the bridge during the time interval under consideration.  Thus the forcing function at position $x$ and time $t$, $0 < t < T$, $0 \le x \le L$, 
should be $\alpha \sin(2\pi t/P)$ for $0 \le x < tv$ and $0$ for $tv < x \le L$.

Comment: Funny, your marching soldiers look like a continous media :) I think, that idealization is the only reason that forcing function isn't the superposition of Dirac's functions?

Comment: On the length-scale of the bridge, the column of soldiers can be thought of as continuous.  If you want to look closer, you still don't need Dirac delta, because the area of contact between boot and road is nonzero.

Comment: Well, I meant Dirac's delta for time-scale. Of course, time of impact can be considered nonzero too.